# Find the sum of the series $1/1 + 1/(1 + 2) + 1/(1 + 2 + 3) + ... = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {\sum_{j=1}^n j}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $1/1 + 1/(1 + 2) + 1/(1 + 2 + 3) + ... = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {\sum_{j=1}^n j}$.

I've been trying to find the sum of the series above by using an inequality of the form:

$\sum_{n = 0}^{k} 2^{-n} \le s_k = \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac {1} {\sum_{j=1}^n j}$

However I need an upper bound that also converges to $2$, and where the inequality holds for some $k \ge K$.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: The sum of the series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)/2}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

The value of the most inside summation is  just 2 / (n (n+ 1)). Then the total summation is 2 k / (1 + k). Then, ...

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed the Gauss sum.

Comment: If you knew the number of things I missed and I still miss ! These do not have any finite limit. Cheers.